# Tensorflow js and MacM1

Tags: macos, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have a running installation of tensorflow-macos and the metal plugin for mac os M1.
Now I want to convert my trained model in a tensorflow js one.

However, when I run
`pip install tensorflowjs` I get an error due to the fact that tensorflow js actually depends on *tensorflow* not on *tensorflow-macos*.

```bash
ERROR: Cannot install tensorflowjs==0.1.0, tensorflowjs==0.1.1, tensorflowjs==0.1.2, tensorflowjs==0.2.0, tensorflowjs==0.2.1, tensorflowjs==0.3.0, tensorflowjs==0.3.1, tensorflowjs==0.4.0, tensorflowjs==0.4.1, tensorflowjs==0.4.2, tensorflowjs==0.5.0, tensorflowjs==0.5.2, tensorflowjs==0.5.4, tensorflowjs==0.5.6, tensorflowjs==0.5.7, tensorflowjs==0.6.0, tensorflowjs==0.6.1, tensorflowjs==0.6.2, tensorflowjs==0.6.4, tensorflowjs==0.6.5, tensorflowjs==0.6.7, tensorflowjs==0.8.0, tensorflowjs==0.8.5, tensorflowjs==0.8.6, tensorflowjs==1.0.1, tensorflowjs==1.1.2, tensorflowjs==1.2.1, tensorflowjs==1.2.10, tensorflowjs==1.2.10.1, tensorflowjs==1.2.2, tensorflowjs==1.2.2.1, tensorflowjs==1.2.3, tensorflowjs==1.2.6, tensorflowjs==1.2.9, tensorflowjs==1.3.1, tensorflowjs==1.3.1.1, tensorflowjs==1.3.2, tensorflowjs==1.4.0, tensorflowjs==1.5.2, tensorflowjs==1.6.0, tensorflowjs==1.7.2, tensorflowjs==1.7.3, tensorflowjs==1.7.4, tensorflowjs==1.7.4.post1, tensorflowjs==2.0.0, tensorflowjs==2.0.1, tensorflowjs==2.0.1.post1, tensorflowjs==2.1.0, tensorflowjs==2.3.0, tensorflowjs==2.4.0, tensorflowjs==2.5.0, tensorflowjs==2.6.0, tensorflowjs==2.7.0, tensorflowjs==2.8.0, tensorflowjs==2.8.1, tensorflowjs==2.8.2, tensorflowjs==2.8.3, tensorflowjs==2.8.4, tensorflowjs==2.8.5, tensorflowjs==3.0.0, tensorflowjs==3.1.0, tensorflowjs==3.11.0, tensorflowjs==3.12.0, tensorflowjs==3.13.0, tensorflowjs==3.14.0, tensorflowjs==3.15.0, tensorflowjs==3.17.0, tensorflowjs==3.18.0, tensorflowjs==3.19.0, tensorflowjs==3.2.0, tensorflowjs==3.20.0, tensorflowjs==3.3.0, tensorflowjs==3.4.0, tensorflowjs==3.5.0, tensorflowjs==3.6.0, tensorflowjs==3.7.0, tensorflowjs==3.8.0 and tensorflowjs==3.9.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflowjs 3.20.0 depends on tensorflow<3 and >=2.1.0
    ...
    tensorflowjs 0.1.1 depends on tensorflow>=1.6.0
    tensorflowjs 0.1.0 depends on tensorflow>=1.6.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: For anyone in my situation: For the moment I am uploading my model folder to colab and convert from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just encountered the same problem.

Here is what worked for me.

Install all dependencies of the tensorflowjs package except tensorflow (since you have tensorflow-macos already installed) and then install tensorflowjs without it dependencies.

Install tensorflowjs dependencies :

`pip install tensorflow_hub jax scipy jaxlib etils`

Install tensorflowjs without its dependencies :

`pip install --no-deps tensorflowjs`